# How to run repetitive task in Handler Thread?

Tags: android, multithreading

How to repeat same task in Handler Thread in specified time delay and update the view in Main thread also.

I need to run this code in background thread repetitively in a interval of 30 seconds and update the result in Main thread as this will block the UI thread if executed here.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int hours = mSeconds/3600;
            int mins = (mSeconds%3600)/60;
            int secs = mSeconds%60;

            String timeElapsed = "";
            if (hours>0){
                timeElapsed = String.format("%02d:%02d",hours,mins);
            }else{
                timeElapsed = String.format("%02d:%02d",mins,secs);
            } 
// there are some other networking stuff also which will be executed here            

            if(mRunning){
                mSeconds++;
            }
// update the view as well

            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);

        }
    });
```

Comment: there are so many ways to do it. Async task, alarm manager. rxjava, Jobschedulers, services. but for this simple task service is suitable.

Answer (score 0):

When you want it to execute.

```
mToastRunnable.run()
```

Fucntion

```
private val mToastRunnable = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        Handler().postDelayed({
        // Do Something.
        }, 7000) //Delay in the running of this function
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 10000)  //Iteration of 10 Sec 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `Handler` for this - it isn't suitable. Without any more information, I'd recommend an `ExecutorService`:

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule(() -> {
    //Run scheduled background task here. Call onto the main thread with 
    // new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> { /*task to execute */ });        
}, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

RxJava is another good candidate if you want to know how much time has elapsed. This syntax is for RxJava 1.x but it will be very similar for RxJava 2.x (I think you'd just swap `Observable` for `Flowable`):

```
Observable.interval(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(interval -> { /* Task. "Interval" is the time elapsed so far */});
```